# Arabic in emacs shown as separate letters

Tags: characters, right-to-left

I am trying to work with Arabic and English texts in the same buffer. They don't have to be in the same paragraphs.

A text like `والإكرام و نوافج` is shown as separate letters.

Contrary to English, in Arabic, the letters should change the form depending on their position (beginning, middle or end). I see the individual: و ا ل إ ك رام و ن وا ف ج.

Emacs recognizes that the Arabic text is left-to-right though. The backspace key deletes the last logical letter, that is,the letter to the right of the cursor.

Comment: What Emacs version are you using, and what font are you using?  Does it happen when you start up Emacs without your init file (from the command line: `emacs -Q`)?

Comment: @Dan: Emacs 24.3, Courier monospace font, it happens without the .emacs too.

Comment: @Dan: if it helps, gedit has no problem connecting the letters, and it's using the fixed width Ubuntu mono font.

Comment: Dejavu sans mono (Linux) on monoco (OS X) both do Arabic correctly for me.

Comment: Can enabling or disabling `auto-composition-mode`help?

Answer (score 6):

I found a solution.

1st run `(print (font-family-list))` and get a full list of all fonts. Pick an installed Arabic font. In my case it was "`clearlyu arabic`".

Add this line to the .emacs file:

`(when window-system (set-fontset-font "fontset-default" '(#x600 . #x6ff) "clearlyu arabic"))`

Change the font name at the end to the name of the font you have installed.